# SQL Plus - Exportar CSV sem a Query no Arquivo

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

Estou tentando exportar o resultado de uma query no SQL PLUS para um CSV. Está funcionando, porém a quero utilizada para extração está vindo nas primeiras linhas do arquivo CSV, o que atrapalha o usuário final. Tem algum comando que eu tenho que acrescentar para que a query não venha junto, somente o resultado?

O comando utilizado para exportação:

```
sqlplus login/senha << EOF

set echo on 
set define on
set feedback off
set serveroutput on
set arraysize 500
set verify off
set pagesize 0
set linesize 10000
ser trimspool on
set termout off

alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

spool /CAMINHO_ABSOLUTO/nome_do_arquivo.csv;

SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO;
```

Comment: Resolvi o problema usando um extrator na linha de comando.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é consequência da forma como os comando estão a ser processados pelo SQLPlus.

O parametro `SET ECHO OFF` (ver descrição em baixo retirada da [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG075)) permite isso mas porque estão a redirecionar o texto para dentro do SQLplus o parametro é ignorado.

```
Controls whether or not to echo commands in a script that is executed with @, @@ or START. 
ON displays the commands on screen. OFF suppresses the display. ECHO does not affect the
display of commands you enter interactively or redirect to SQL*Plus from the operating system.
```

Se o conteudo do bloco EOF for colocado num ficheiro isolado e a invocação passar a ser:

```
sqlplus login/senha @sql_script
```

A pesquisas deixaram de constar no ficheiro referido no comando `SPOOL`.

Comment: A pergunta foi do "plus" mas no SqlDeveloper se aplica ? Como ?